# Totalizing scores for multiple words filtering

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working with a document finder which inputs an N amount of words and is supposed to search all those N words hitting the same column. Those N words are ordered and if the first and the second words matched different documents the documents matched by the first word would need to come with a higher scoring. So far I've got this:

```
{
"from": 0, 
"query": {
    "custom_filters_score": {
        "filters": [
            {
                "boost": 10, 
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "descripcion": "lost"
                    }
                }
            }, 
            {
                "boost": 9, 
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "format": "in"
                    }
                }
            }
        ], 
    "query":{...(mandatory conditions regardless of the search pattenrs)...}}
    }
} 
}
```

This works decently in the sense that if it matches the first word it will boost higher than the second word. However, the problem is that I need that if it matches both the first and second word the total scoring is the sum of both filters and not just the highest.
In the example above the document containing the description: "lost in space" should score higher than the one containing "lost".

Do I need to sum the scores from both filters in a script? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use elasticsearch 0.90.4?  If so, custom_filters_score is deprecated and replaced by [function score query][1]: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

With a function score query, you can specify that the scores should be summed:

```
{
  "from": 0, 
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
        "functions" : [
            {
                "boost": 10, 
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "descripcion": "lost"
                    }
                }
            }, 
            {
                "boost": 9, 
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "format": "in"
                    }
                }
            }
        ], 
        "query":{...(mandatory conditions regardless of the search pattenrs)...},
        "score_mode" : "sum"
    }
  } 
}
```